# distances = np.sqrt(((X - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2)) error : list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

```
def kmeans(X,k,max_iter = 100):
    n = 5610
    d = 1
    centroids= []
    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randint(0 , 5610)
        centroids.append(X[a])
    for i in range(max_iter):
        distances = np.sqrt(((X - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))
        lable = np.argmin(distances,axis=0)
        
        new_centroids = np.array([X[lable==j].mean(axis=0) for j in range(k)])
        
        if np.allclose(centroids , new_centroids):
            break
        centroids = new_centroids
    return lable , centroids
```

I wrote this code but got this error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `centroids` is a plain Python list. You need to convert it to a numpy array before doing numpy-style indexing on it.

Comment: worked for me ubuntu 5x python and also other compiled libraries and released updates fixes using related commands -S --rthch --register log etc... different SO environments could be platforms issues

Answer (score 0):

```
def kmeans(X,k,max_iter = 100):
    n = 5610
    
    centroids_list= []
    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randint(0 , n)
        centroids_list.append(X[a])
    centroids = np.array(centroids_list)
   
    for i in range(max_iter):
        distances = np.sqrt(((X[np.newaxis] - centroids[:,np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))
        labels = np.argmin(distances,axis=0)
        
        new_centroids = np.array([X[labels==j].mean(axis=0) for j in range(k)])
        
        if np.allclose(centroids , new_centroids):
            break
        centroids = new_centroids
    return labels , centroids
```